# Jenkin unable to catch Talend build exemption exit code

Tags: talend

I have configured a Jenkins job to call Talend data integration job Build.
The Talend components in job are check boxed with die on error. When talend job fails it displays the error but the jenkins job still shows it as success.

How to catch talend failure exit code in jenkin.

I have enabled die on error for each component in Talend job build

D:\JENKINS-WS\Cloud_Insights\workspace\E2CI-DB-ORACLE-SJ-INTEGRATION\TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI>java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .;../lib/routines.jar;../lib/activation.jar;../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar;../lib/mail-1.4.jar;trigger_load_oracle_sj_db_to_e2ci_0_1.jar;load_oracle_sj_db_stg_to_fct_0_1.jar;load_oracle_sj_db_csv_to_stg_0_1.jar;load_oracle_sj_db_stg_to_dim_0_1.jar;load_oracle_sj_db_dim_to_lu_0_1.jar; e2ci_db_integration.trigger_load_oracle_sj_db_to_e2ci_0_1.TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI --context=DEV
tRunJob_1 in TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI call LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG with:

Exception in component tRunJob_1 (TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Child job returns 1. It doesn't terminate normally.
Exception in component tFileList_1 (LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No file found in directory \prod4271\E2CI-DBOPS\IN
    at e2ci_db_integration.load_oracle_sj_db_csv_to_stg_0_1.LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG.tFileList_1Process(LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG.java:1421)
    at e2ci_db_integration.load_oracle_sj_db_csv_to_stg_0_1.LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG.runJobInTOS(LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG.java:5292)
    at e2ci_db_integration.load_oracle_sj_db_csv_to_stg_0_1.LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG.main(LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_CSV_TO_STG.java:5131)

```
at e2ci_db_integration.trigger_load_oracle_sj_db_to_e2ci_0_1.TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI.tRunJob_1Process(TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI.java:736)
at e2ci_db_integration.trigger_load_oracle_sj_db_to_e2ci_0_1.TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI.runJobInTOS(TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI.java:3192)
at e2ci_db_integration.trigger_load_oracle_sj_db_to_e2ci_0_1.TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI.main(TRIGGER_LOAD_ORACLE_SJ_DB_TO_E2CI.java:3031)
```

Triggering a new build of E2CI-DB-ORACLE-CHG-INTEGRATION
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: What do you mean "call Talend data integration job Build" ? Does the jenkins job build your talend job ? If so, how ?

Comment: updated the question with how jenkin is calling the talend job (.bat file). This also explain even when the talend job (.bat file) fails the jenkins still shows it as success.